# Android GraphView make only x axes horizontal scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-graphview

I'm using graphView library to draw a line graph in my android app. Since my x axes has more data, I want to make it horizontal scrollable, so that datas will not overlap with each other on smaller devices. So far I tried to add a HorizontalScrollView in my xml showed below, and it is able to make the whole graph scroll.
My question is: if I want Y axes stay and only X axes scrollable, how to do that? Are there any GraphView api available?

My xml:

```
      <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/graph_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CustomFontTextView
                style=""
                android:layout_marginTop=""
                android:layout_marginBottom=""
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="graph_header" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Graph"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/talkback_graph"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

My java code:

```
 public void setGraphView(Map<Integer, Integer> dt,String[] horizontalLabels ){
    GraphViewData[] graphData = new GraphViewData[dt.size()];
    int graphPos=0;

    for(int pos:dt.keySet())
    {
        graphData[graphPos++] = new GraphViewData(pos, dt.get(pos));
    }

    GraphViewSeries series = new GraphViewSeries(graphData); 
    LineGraphView lineGraphView = new  LineGraphView( getMainActivity(), "" );
    lineGraphView.setScrollable(true);
    lineGraphView.setScalable(false);
    lineGraphView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    lineGraphView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    lineGraphView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    lineGraphView.setManualYAxisBounds(500, 300);
    lineGraphView.setDrawDataPoints(true);
    lineGraphView.setDataPointsRadius(14f);
    lineGraphView.getGraphViewStyle().setGridColor(Color.RED);
    lineGraphView.setHorizontalLabels(horizontalLabels);
    lineGraphView.setVerticalLabels(new String[]{"max 500", "min 300"});
    lineGraphView.getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_size));
    lineGraphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsWidth(70);
    lineGraphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    lineGraphView.addSeries(series);
    graphView.addView(lineGraphView);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

lineGraphView.setScrollableY(true);
lineGraphView.setScalableY(false);

for Y axis, it should use different api.